# How to replace a character at random in a string?

Tags: c, string, random, replace

I've printed a string of "+" symbols based on two given values(N, M). Now I'm trying to figure out how to replace characters at random in said string based on a third given value(K). The characters are stored in a string(l). I think I have to use the replace function but I don't know how(hence why it's in a comment for now). Any help is appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int randaux()
{
  static long seed=1;
  return(((seed = seed * 214013L + 2531011L) >> 16) & 0x7fff);
}

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char s[1000];
    int N, M, K, l;

    printf("N: ");
    scanf("%d",&N);
    printf("M: ");
    scanf("%d",&M);
    printf("K: ");
    scanf("%d",&K);
    printf("\n");

    gets(s);

    l=strlen(s);

    /* Mostre um tabuleiro de N linhas e M colunas */

    if(N*M<K){
    printf("Not enough room.");
    }else if(N>40){
    printf("Min size 1, max size 40.");
    }else if(M>40){
    printf("Min size 1, max size 40.");
    }else{      
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {

    for(int j=0; j<M; j++)
    {
    printf("+", s[j]);
    }   

    printf("\n", s[i]);
    }
    for(int l=0; l<K; l++)
    {
    /*s.replace();*/
    }
}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Not only is `randaux()` not called, but if it were, it uses the same seed each time.

Comment: Are you trying to "recycle" code you found, but not written yourself? It is possible, but unlikely, that the commented-out `s.replace();` is C code.

Comment: @Weather Vane randaux isn't called because I don't know when to call it. The seed is static at the moment to test with static results.

Comment: `s` is a character array.  It does not have member functions, so `s.replace()` would not be valid here.

Comment: What do you want to replace the characters with?

Comment: @Weather Vane I put the `s.replace();` in a comment. s is the string. replace is what I think you have to use to replace characters inside the string.

Comment: @ eddiem the character chosen at random will be replaced with a # character.

Comment: It isn't.  You simply use their array indices to replace them.  For example:  `s[10] = 'x';`

Comment: Is `K` the number of characters you want to replace?  But the actual indices of those characters are to be determined at random?

Comment: @ eddiem So you don't have to use the replace function? So I would have to do a for loop that did `s[]= '#';` where s is the result of the function, right? (also, apologies to everyone if it's worded poorly, english isn't my first language)

Comment: You could do that, but you would need to modify either the `randaux()` function or `&` off additional bits, since the maximum value that could current be returned is `0x7fff`, much larger than the bounds of your array.

Comment: @eddiem Yes, k is the number of characters to be replaced. The indices are to be determined at random.

Comment: There are multiple issues in the code as it is presented.  Is `s` supposed to be a two-dimensional matrix?

Answer (score 2):

There is too much unexplained complexity and unknowns in your program to enable a corrective answer. But this shows how to replace a textual string's character at random, with a numeral.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[] = "----------";
    int len = strlen(str);
    int index;
    int num;

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));    // randomise once only in the program
    printf("%s\n", str);            // original string

    index = rand() % len;           // get random index to replace, in length range
    num = '0' + rand() % 10;        // get random number, in decimal digit range
    str[index] = num;               // overwrite string character

    printf("%s\n", str);            // altered string
    return 0;
}
```

Program sessions:

```
----------
-3--------

----------
-----0----

----------
--------6-
```

Arguably it would be better to use `size_t` types, but for the limited range of the example, will suffice.